# Is there an an AWS sdk to parse AWS cloudformation YAML and convert into XML or JSON

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jackson, aws-sdk

I'm finding that the Jackson Library cannot effectively handle the !Sub syntax in AWS cloudformation. For example the below cannot be converted into XML using the XMLMapper.

```
    UserData:
    # This script below is to install AmazonCloudWatchAgent, restart AmazonCloudWatchAgent and tell the result to cloudformation.
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
       #!/bin/bash
       rpm -Uvh https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
       /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region} --configsets default
       /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Is there an AWS SDK in JAVA that can read AWS YAML and then convert it into XML or JSON?

Or alternatively is there an AWS SDK that can load the extended cloudformation YAML syntax into java objects?

Greetings
Conteh

Comment: YAML parsers can't handle the AWS extended syntax either, afaik. Why do you want to convert YAML to XML?

Comment: To make the YAML data processable via XSLT. @jarmod I've added a second alternative question.